# strcat and segmentation fault 11

Tags: c, string, printf, strcat

my code is as follows:

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <math.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   int string_length(char*);
   void reverse(char*);
   int main(void)
   {
      char num[256];
      printf("%c[%d;%d;%dmPlease enter a number of rows: ", 0x1B, 5, 32, 40);
      gets(num);
      //gets number

printf("%c[%dm\n", 0x1B, 0);
//Resets color

//Variables
char revnum[50], q[50] = "\0", r[50] = "\v";
int i, x, j, z, w;

//Reverses inputted character string
reverse(num);

//Takes reversed inputted character string and out puts it as an integer
for(i = 0; num[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    j = -(48-num[i]);
    double y = i;
    x = j*pow(10, y) + x;
}

//Takes integer version of inputted character string and assigns a counter's value (counting up to our integer version) to a character string
for (z = 0; z <= x; z++) {
    sprintf(revnum, "%d", z);

    //Takes the new character string for each number up to the inputted value and prints it vertically, but no differentiating between numbers and printing them horizontally to each other
    for (w = 0; revnum[w] != '\0'; ++w) {
        strcat(q, r);
        printf("%s", q);
        strcat(q, revnum[w]);
      }
   }

  }

  //Function which reverses a character string
   void reverse(char *num)
{
int length, c;
char *begin, *end, temp;

length = string_length(num);

begin = num;
end = num;

for ( c = 0 ; c < ( length - 1 ) ; c++ )
    end++;

for ( c = 0 ; c < length/2 ; c++ )
{
    temp = *end;
    *end = *begin;
    *begin = temp;

    begin++;
    end--;
}
}

 int string_length(char *pointer)
 {
int c = 0;

while( *(pointer+c) != '\0' )
    c++;

return c;
}
```

the point of the program is to output all the numbers before a number inputted with the digits of each number vertical and then the numbers themselves listed horizontally.

please help!!!

Comment: Try running your program in a debugger. It will help you by telling you where the crash is, let you walk the function call stack so you can see how you ended up there, and let you examine variable to help you figure out the reason.

Comment: There are a couple of things though: Why do you make your own string length function, when `strlen` is perfectly fine? And instead of looping to find the end of the string in `reverse` you could just add `(length - 1)` to the pointer.

Comment: However, the main problem _might_ be that you don't initialize all variables you use. If you use e.g. the option `-Wall` to GCC when compiling you would get a warning about this.

Comment: You should be getting at least one compiler warnings from your compiler. If you are, fix your code until it compiles cleanly. If you aren't, find out how to increase your compiler's warning level. `strcat(q, revnum[w]);` passes a `char` as the second argument to `strcat`; it requires a `char*`. And *never* use the `gets()` function; it's inherently unsafe.

Comment: `string_length`? Is there some problem with the standard C `strlen()` which we've all been unaware of for the last 30 years? :-)

Comment: If you do "man strcat" in terminal the specification says:
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
 Try strcat(q, &revnum[w]);
In general if one uses 
char q[50];
char *r = "hello" 
strcat(q,r) that you have done works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You've made several mistakes. This code works:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int string_length(char*);
void reverse(char*);
int main(void)
{
  char num[256];
  printf("Please enter a number of rows: ", 0x1B, 5, 32, 40);
  gets(num);
  //gets number

//Variables
char revnum[50], q[50] = "\0";
int i, x, j, z, w;

//Reverses inputted character string
reverse(num);

//Takes reversed inputted character string and out puts it as an integer
x = atoi(num);

//Takes integer version of inputted character string and assigns a counter's value (counting up to our integer version) to a character string
for (z = 0; z <= x; z++) {
sprintf(revnum, "%d", z);

//Takes the new character string for each number up to the inputted value and prints it vertically, but no differentiating between numbers and printing them horizontally to each other
for (w = 0; revnum[w] != '\0'; ++w) {
    printf("%s\v", q);
char a[2];
sprintf(a,"%c",revnum[w]);
strcat(q,a);
  }
}

}

//Function which reverses a character string
void reverse(char *num)
{
int length, c;
char *begin, *end, temp;

length = string_length(num);

begin = num;
end = num;

for ( c = 0 ; c < ( length - 1 ) ; c++ )
end++;

for ( c = 0 ; c < length/2 ; c++ )
{
temp = *end;
*end = *begin;
*begin = temp;

 begin++;
 end--;
}
}

int string_length(char *pointer)
{
int c = 0;

while( *(pointer+c) != '\0' )
c++;

return c;
}
```

And compile with option *-fno-stack-protector* to prevent stack smaching detection.